# Clear apt-file cache

Tags: apt, apt-file

How do I clear the cache created by running `apt-file update`?
Also, is there a way to see how much space the cache is currently using?

Answer (score -1):

Refer post: https://www.computerhope.com/unix/apt-file.htm   &
https://wiki.debian.org/apt-file

apt-file purge

Purge the user cache. An apt-file update will be needed before a search can be performed on the user cache. If the user cache doesn't exist, the system-wide cache can be used for user searches.

```
Purge
```

Clear "Contents-" files from the apt-file cache directory. If you receive any errors listing or searching, it's a good idea to perform a purge and then an update.

To delete the system wide cache use:

```
sudo apt-file purge
```

related directories:

```
 ~/.cache/apt-file
/var/cache/apt/apt-file
```

Comment: I'm not sure when, but at some point the `purge` action was removed. For example it is present in [Ubuntu Trusty 14](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages//trusty/man1/apt-file.1.html) but not in [Ubuntu Focal 20](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/apt-file.1.html)

Comment: Try removing cache files using sudo rm . Some thing like given on the same page http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/apt-file.1.html.

Comment: Neither of the two directories you shared are present in my system (Focal). Perhaps the new version of `apt-file` shares the cache info with `apt`. [This line](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/apt-file.1.html) in the docs makes me think so: _"The apt-file command relies on the APT configuration. Notably, the default configuration makes `apt` fetch Contents files by default during a call to `apt update`."_

Comment: I think this answer is not valid for Ubuntu since it does not support purging in its apt-file version.